# How to solve over(too many) partition issue in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata

What is the issue will occur if I have more partition in single table. I am planning to create a history table in hive it will contains 7 to 8 year data also I am planning to partition the table with date key. In this case my table will have approximately 2500 to 3500 partitions. Does this over partition will create problem into my namenode and datanode? Each entry partition entry how much memory will occupy into the namenode? What are problem I will face because of this over partition? If I will face memory issue please suggest me the solution. If you found any good article about this please give me link.
Is there any alternative method available to solve this issue?

Thanks
Venkadesan E

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're struggling with over-partitioning, 3.5K still sound ok. The only issue with the larger number of partitions is the time before the query starts running, i suppose it because of receiving partitions metadata from metastore. We encountered real slowdown on 10k partitions, 3.5k should work for you

Comment: Hi 
Is there a solution of this as of now we have around 14k partitions and the query never starts (waited for over 1.5-2 hours) its stuck in Map initialization phase with number of mappers = -1
Thanks a in advance